# Ignore Windows-L key and Send L (unpress Windows key)

Tags: autohotkey

I would like Windows-L to behave just like L. I have tried

```
#L::L
```

But this will not unpress the Windows key, so it's kind of a loop and does not do anything. How can I unpress the Windows key?

**Update**: I think with Windows-L I have chosen a particularly difficult example. So let's perhaps focus on Windows-+ (the magnifier shortcut).

Same thing, this does nothing:

```
#+::+
```

Comment: I think this may be impossible.  [This page](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) talks about overriding all of the OS-default Windows-key hotkeys using the registry.  That's not exactly what you're trying to do, but it mentions that even this low-level global method doesn't work for the Win-L and Win-U keys.  I think these hotkeys might just be detected by Windows before AHK can do anything.

Comment: + is interpreted as a shift key modifier... see help topic for hotkeys for a list of special symbols.  You may need to read the SC equivalent after pressing the key (Tray > Open > View > Key HIstory) and use the SC code for the hotkey definition.

Answer (score 0):

Untested...

```
SendMode, Input
#IfWinActive
#l::
    keywait, LWin
    send, l
return
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no (still locks screen).

Comment: Yeah I forgot that's the default hotkey for locking the workstation... that one definitely can't be reassigned

Answer (score 0):

For `+`, this works:

```
#+::Send {+}
```

A possible explanation has been given [here](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=69146).

For `L`, however, this still does not work:

```
#L::Send {L}
```